# Using ffmpeg to cut a portion of a mkv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, matroska

So I'm trying to extract a portion of a video but for some reason the output file has a higher bitrate than the original!

The original has a 9 mbps bitrate and the resulting file has like 21.9 mbps!

The command I'm using is

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mkv" -codec copy -ss 00:41:04 -t 00:04:34 out.mkv
```

output is

```
frame=  239 fps= 48 q=-1.0 size=   15361kB time=00:00:19.19 bitrate=6554.2kbits
frame= 1155 fps=210 q=-1.0 size=   84184kB time=00:00:57.58 bitrate=11975.1kbits
frame= 1695 fps=282 q=-1.0 size=  148607kB time=00:01:19.88 bitrate=15239.6kbits
frame= 2395 fps=368 q=-1.0 size=  223358kB time=00:01:49.11 bitrate=16768.4kbits
frame= 2851 fps=406 q=-1.0 size=  281783kB time=00:02:08.07 bitrate=18023.8kbits
frame= 3453 fps=459 q=-1.0 size=  350682kB time=00:02:33.14 bitrate=18759.1kbits
frame= 4295 fps=536 q=-1.0 size=  422931kB time=00:03:08.31 bitrate=18397.8kbits
frame= 4767 fps=559 q=-1.0 size=  479239kB time=00:03:27.88 bitrate=18885.3kbits
frame= 5137 fps=569 q=-1.0 size=  534715kB time=00:03:43.54 bitrate=19595.4kbits
frame= 5585 fps=586 q=-1.0 size=  601128kB time=00:04:02.03 bitrate=20345.8kbits
frame= 6170 fps=615 q=-1.0 size=  684139kB time=00:04:26.60 bitrate=21021.8kbits
frame= 6355 fps=624 q=-1.0 Lsize=  707003kB time=00:04:33.99 bitrate=21138.3kbits/s
```

Does anybody know how come the output has 21.9 mbps when the input has 9 mbps? I thought `-copy` is not supposed to re-encode !?

Comment: You need to include the complete console output. How are you calculating the bitrate? What are the file sizes?

Comment: I used mediainfo to check out the bitrate. The output file size is around 700 MB, and it has 4 minutes. The file size of the input is around 7 GB and has almost 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re-muxed segment has a higher average bitrate than the original, but that does not necessarily mean that any re-encoding occurred.

The section you are [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) probably has more complex scenes than the average scenes from the rest of the video, and your input is likely not using a constant bitrate, so the bitrate increases upon more complex scenes.

I had to make some assumptions because you did not provide any info about your input, or the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: I think you are right :(